# Is fail2ban necessary?

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I have disabled the root login, disabled the password authentication option, and blocked all ports except 22 and 80 for a linux virtual server I run.

The only way to access the server is with a 4096 bit RSA key.

Is it necessary to run fail2ban as well?

Apart from keeping the logs a bit cleaner, is the added security worth the overhead?

Comment: What overhead? If nothing else, it'll stop people from attempting thousands/millions of passwords.

Comment: I don't see why this would be opinion-based. Password guessing is a non-issue on a server configured to only allow keys. And using fail2ban could lock yourself out from the server - accessing the server through a CGN would increase the risk of yourself getting locked out. So as far as I can tell an entirely objective answer would be that using fail2ban would not be a good idea in the mentioned scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You also seem to be focusing on just ssh. Fail2ban has many other jails for other services.

Security is like an onion, many layers make it up. Fail2ban is just another layer of the onion. If you don't think it's necessary then don't use it no one is forcing you to do so.